# Xcode - Instruments - Leaks: Plain Not Working... Can we debug leaks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-4.2

Basically

what is happening is I was using leaks and it was being flakey, Working correctly at random times and not others. And now it decided just not to work, I launch it from Xcode Run -> Run with PErformance Tool -> leaks and it starts launching the application but stops and appears to crash.

I don't have any warnings, errors or even analyzer marks.

So... Is there a way to debug Instruments? or at least see why it's crashing the App?

The annoying part is I know I have 5 small leaks left that I may or may not have fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Instruments has a crash log out in the library... Did the trick to find out what my problem was.